# How to write batch files correctly for publication Adding different precompiled macros during .NET programming?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, dotnet-publish

I have the following code:

```
#if PC
    var rootPath = Path.Combine("dist");
#else
    var rootPath = Path.Combine(@"/bin/bash");
#endif
```

I want to write different batch files when publishing the program to decide whether to add the macro "PC" or not.

But I didn't find the answer under the dotnet publish command.

Comment: That's not a macro. The switches for conditional compilation can be configured in csproj and then depend on your build profile (if you're building for "debug" or "release" for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a configuration (Pc) in your .csproj file, and add the `PC` symbol:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Pc|AnyCPU'">
       <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);PC</DefineConstants>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

   Use `-c` option to pick this configuration:

   ```
   dotnet publish -c:Pc
   ```
2. Use msbuild's `-getProperty` and `-p` options to define the symbols:

   ```
   SET cmdGetProp='dotnet msbuild -getProperty:DefineConstants'
   FOR /F "tokens=*" %%s IN (%cmdGetProp%) DO SET prop=%%s
   dotnet publish -p:DefineConstants=\"%prop%;PC\"
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your two methods, but the first one doesn't seem to be built using the release configuration, as I found that the generated file size is much larger than that generated using the release configuration.

Comment: That's a new configuration, if you want it based on the release, you need to copy all the properties from the release configuration to this one.

Comment: ok...thanks, if i append <Optimize>true</Optimize>, it works well.